# Creating Robust and Flexible grid system that can handle a wide range of box sizes without compromising the overall user experience

Tags: reactjs, next.js, layout, tailwind-css, css-grid

I made this component, when you click on create a new template a modal pops up with some values that allow you to create a box and those values will be on that box, when you click on one of those values another div appears that allows you to choose the col and row span of the box which works barely, after some boxes the ui just breaks, I need the ability to create custom boxes which allow you to select the col and row span of the box, allowing to add boxes of varying sizes. And enough space to accommodate the new boxes, and the result is not a distorted UI/UX that doesn't match the user's expectations.

Ultimately, I'm asking to create a more robust and flexible system that can handle a wide range of box sizes without compromising the overall user experience. I only use React and Tailwind i can not use any other thing.Sorry if the english is bad.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface Box {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  graph: string;
  colSpan?: string;
  rowSpan?: string;
}

const boxes: Box[] = [
  {
    name: 'string',
    graph: 'graph',
  },
  {
    name: 'boolean',
    graph: 'linear',
  },
  {
    name: 'number',
    graph: 'point',
  },
  {
    name: 'unknown',
    graph: 'area',
  },
  {
    name: 'any',
    graph: 'radar',
  },
  {
    name: 'function',
    graph: 'bar',
  },
];

const OPTIONS = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];

const Templates = () => {
  const [boksat, setBoksat] = useState<Box[]>([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [chooseSize, setChooseSize] = useState(false);
  const [selectedBox, setSelectedBox] = useState<Box | null>(null);
  const [rowSpan, setRowSpan] = useState('');
  const [colSpan, setColSpan] = useState('');

  const addBox = (box: Box) => {
    const newBox = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 20)),
      ...box,
      colSpan: selectedBox?.colSpan || colSpan,
      rowSpan: selectedBox?.rowSpan || rowSpan,
    };
    setBoksat((prevBoksat) => [...prevBoksat, newBox]);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Row span: ${rowSpan}, Col span: ${colSpan}`);
    addBox(selectedBox)
    console.log('boksat', boksat)
  };

  const Modal = () => (
    <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 flex items-center justify-center z-50">
      <div className="bg-[#E2E8F0] p-8 rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-auto w-auto">
        {chooseSize ? (
          <div className="bg-white h-auto w-[300px] p-5 rounded-xl">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="max-w-md mx-auto">
              <div className="flex flex-col mb-6">
                <label htmlFor="row-span" className="mb-2 font-medium text-gray-700">
                  Row Span:
                </label>
                <div className="relative">
                  <select
                    id="row-span"
                    name="row-span"
                    value={rowSpan}
                    onChange={(event) => setRowSpan(event.target.value)}
                    className="block appearance-none w-full px-4 py-2 pr-8 leading-tight border border-gray-300 rounded focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-500"
                  >
                    <option value="">Select an option</option>
                    {OPTIONS.map((option) => (
                      <option key={option} value={option}>
                        {option}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                  <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 pointer-events-none">
                    <svg className="w-4 h-4 fill-current text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                      <path fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd" d="M12.59 7.59L10 10.17l-2.59-2.58L6 9l4 4 4-4-1.41-1.41z" />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="flex flex-col mb-6">
                <label htmlFor="col-span" className="mb-2 font-medium text-gray-700">
                  Col Span:
                </label>
                <div className="relative">
                  <select
                    id="col-span"
                    name="col-span"
                    value={colSpan}
                    onChange={(event) => setColSpan(event.target.value)}
                    className="block appearance-none w-full px-4 py-2 pr-8 leading-tight border border-gray-300 rounded focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-500"
                  >
                    <option value="">Select an option</option>
                    {OPTIONS.map((option) => (
                      <option key={option} value={option}>
                        {option}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                  <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 pointer-events-none">
                    <svg className="w-4 h-4 fill-current text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                      <path fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd" d="M12.59 7.59L10 10.17l-2.59-2.58L6 9l4 4 4-4-1.41-1.41z" />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='flex justify-center gap-5'>
              <button
                className="mt-4 bg-green-500 text-white px-4 mr-5 rounded-lg"
                type='submit'
              >
                Add box
              </button>

              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setShowModal(false);
                  setChooseSize(false);
                }}
                className="mt-4 bg-red-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg"
              >
                Close
              </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5">
            {boxes.map((box, i) => (
              <div
                className="grid col-span-1 justify-around bg-white rounded-xl h-[100px] w-[100px] cursor-pointer"
                key={i}
                onClick={() => {
                  setChooseSize(true);
                  setSelectedBox(box);
                }}
              >
                {box.graph}
              </div>
            ))}
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setShowModal(false);
                setChooseSize(false);
              }}
              className="mt-4 bg-red-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg"
            >
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const deleteBox = (id: number = 0) => {
    setBoksat((prevBoksat) => prevBoksat.filter((b) => b.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {showModal && <Modal />}
      <div className="relative bg-[#E2E8F0] w-auto rounded-xl mb-6 p-5">
        <button className="bg-white absolute right-10 p-2 rounded-3xl" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
          Create a new template
        </button>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-12 grid-rows-6 pt-10 gap-3">
          {boksat.map((box, i) => (
            <div className={`col-span-${box.colSpan} row-span-${box.rowSpan} h-full bg-white rounded-xl m-5 relative`} key={i}>
              <div>{box.graph}</div>
              <div className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 flex gap-2 p-2">
                <button className="p-2 bg-red-400 rounded-3xl" onClick={() => deleteBox(box.id)}>
                  Delete Template
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Templates;
```